Why do Japanese people pronouce the word "Mach" as マッハ instead of マッカ?
Why do Japanese people pronouce the word "Mach"  as マッハ instead of マッカ?

If you mean this guy, it is just because マッハ is closer to the German pronunciation. Similarly for バッハ/Bach.

I wonder why English speakers don't pronounce the final sound of van Gogh the same way as the final sound of Bach.

@aguijonazo To the English ear, van Gogh and Bach don't quite sound the same.  The "gh" is somehow breathier.  But, there are folks who pronounce it as "van Goff" others as "van Goe".  It's English, so there's usually very little logic in how we borrow pronunciations from other languages.

A cute pronunciation guide to van Gogh in English

Why do English speakers pronounce the word 酒 as if it was the word 先?

I could just as easily ask why English people pronounce "loch" as "lock"

@Leebo I love the point you raise. The difference between "e" and "i" at the end of a word in English is near impossible.  Surely there is a linguistic term for pronunciation patterns where vowels in certain word positions assimilate into a particular sound.  Unaccented vowels often have very little discernible difference in pronunciation.  But when I first learned Japanese, hearing the difference between かいます and かえます was very challenging.  Making sure to pronounce さけ and さき correctly took deliberate effort.

Check how Vienna is said in Japanese !

@A.Ellett - I've never thought the English speakers who pronounce 酒 like 先 are trying to imitate the Japanese sound. I thought they were just reading out the spelling "sake" trying not to pronounce it like the English word of the same spelling. I think if you tell them the final "e" is similar to the final sound of French "fiancé", I think they would at least be able to say "sahkay".

@aguijonazo I agree.  If you point out the nuance of the pronunciation, I think most English speakers will make the effort to pronounce the words as close as possible.

'Mach' is a German word. In German it is pronounced either as /max/ with /x/ or /maχ/ with /χ/, a voiceless velar fricative and voiceless uvular fricative respectively. These sounds tend to sound much like /h/ or /k/ to people who don't speak languages that have them; indeed, with Spanish words like 'José', English speakers do tend to use /h/ rather than /k/. We don't use it in Bach because English doesn't allow syllable-final H, but Japanese doesn't allow most consonants in the coda anyway.
